# self-hosting OWIN in windows service, no configuration method.

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am attempting to self-host OWIN in a windows service. When I debug through visual studio 2017 it works great, but when I try to run the service in a release build I get the following error.

Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
 - No 'Configuration' method was found in class '., Vps.SysComm.Service, Version=3.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.ResolveApp(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(IServiceProvider services, StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](StartOptions options)
   at ..()
   at ..(String[] )

What is interesting is the . for startup class name.

This is my startup class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Vps.SysComm.Service.Startup))]
namespace Vps.SysComm.Service
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
        // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

inside my Main service start method

```
  string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000";
  _sysCommAPI = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
```

Comment: Are there more then one startup classes and maybe mixed up namespaces?

Comment: Actually @BoasEnkler you were right to an extent. I was building obfuscated and for some reason, It could not match up the namespaces. Which Is why I think they were blank. Once I built un-obfuscated it worked. Thanks. Still not sure how to make it work obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  Thread.Sleep(100); inside Configuration method.
Hope It will work.